# do all the subclass's constructors with parameters needs super(args) when superclass only have one constructor with parameters?

Tags: java

```
class Animal{
    String s;
    Animal(String s){
        this.s = s;     
    }   
}


class Dog extends Animal{
    Animal animal;
    Dog(String s) {
        super(s);       
    }
    //here is an error "Implicit super constructor Animal() is undefined.Must explicitly invoke another constructor"
    Dog(Animal animal){
        this.animal = animal;       
    }   
}
```

my confuse is, I've already called the superclass's constructor-with-parameters in

```
Dog(String s) {
    super(s);       
}
```

but why I still get the error message in another constructor Dog(Animal animal)?

How the constructor mechanism works in this example?

Thanks!

Comment: As ScaryWombat said, you probably don't want the `Dog(Animal animal)` constructor.  However, I want to correct another mistake.  It is very much possible for a class to have two or more constructors.  However, when an object is created, only one of the constructors is called, not both.  So the way you wrote it, when some other code says `new Dog`, it calls _either_ the one with the string parameter _or_ the one with the animal parameter.  Not both (unless you tell one constructor to call the other).  So your statement "I've already called the superclass's constructor..." is wrong.

Comment: I think you fundamentally misunderstand how constructors work, especially in subclasses, and you should go back and study a tutorial on the subject.

Comment: @ajb Thank you,your answer really helps a lot:-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

And the answer to your question is simply: yes.

Any subclass constructor *must* first make a call to super. If the superclass has only one ctor taking some arguments, then those "super calls" in your sub classes have to use that ctor.

Comment: Thanks for your answer:-)

Comment: You are very welcome; thank you for the quick accept!

Answer (score 4):

Your code is incorrect.  As `Dog` extends `Animal` then `Dog` does not need (and should not have) a `Animal` Object

The correct way is

```
class Animal{
    String s;
    Animal(String s){
        this.s = s;     
    }  

    // add a setter and getter
    public String getS () {return s;}
    public void setS (String s) {this.s = s;} 
}


class Dog extends Animal{
    Dog(String s) {
        super(s);       
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you then access `Animal` then? `super(s); s.Animal;` ?

Comment: You should have methods on `Animal` that return what you want e.g. `String getS () {return s;}`  In your code `Dog` **isa** `Animal`

Comment: I have added a setter and getter to show how to access super's fields

Comment: Can you explain me why dog can not have animal object.

Comment: @ScaryWombat : What if you want to have a an association between animals then you really need a pattern like this, Dog is associated with any animal with some relation lets say enemy (cat), Then we need to have such relations.

Comment: @KiranKumar in that case it would be `Dog` **isa** `Animal` and `Dog` **hasa** `Animal`

Comment: Yes, exactly. We can encounter such scenarios.

Comment: and in that situation you would have setter for `void setEnemy (Animal cat)`

Comment: Thanks for your answers,as Kiran Kumar saids,this examlpe in facts came from my test of "Decorator Pattern",so there is a superclass object in the subclass object to let the Dog-class have accociation with the other subclass.And your answers help a lot:-)